# It is posible to create a hotkey in a Delphi console application?

Tags: delphi, winapi, console

I tried:

```
RegisterHotKey(GetConsoleWindow(),$29A,MOD_ALT,'a')
```

but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `RegisterHotKey()` takes 4 parameters. I see only 3.

Comment: added the parameter now can you answer my question ?

Comment: -1 for your bad attitude in your comments to @David, particularly the one in his deleted answer.

Comment: @Andreas I think that's a bit harsh. I wasn't offended by anything in this thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a message loop to receive WMHotKey messages. Do you have a message loop in your console application?

**Edit:**

Try capital 'A' instead of 'a'. Because the last parameter of [`RegisterHotkey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) wants a Virtual-key code. And the [virtual-key code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28VS.85%29.aspx) of letter A is 0x41 = 'A'.

Comment: @opc0de You say "of course I have", but since you gave no details whatsoever in your question beyond "it doesn't work", we are reduced to guesswork. Please take the time to add more details if you want us to help.

Comment: +1 Given the paucity of information, this is the most probable cause of a problem.

Comment: I will try that and come back with a result

Comment: @David: Yay, you gave me my second new word today. Never heard of paucity before. Somebody else on SO gave me discombobulate. Me like!  :-)